# Google FooBar Bringing a Gun to a Guard Fight

Tags: python

I'm stuck on this problem:

> Uh-oh - you've been cornered by one of Commander Lambdas elite guards! Fortunately, you grabbed a beam weapon from an abandoned guard post while you were running through the station, so you have a chance to fight your way out. But the beam weapon is potentially dangerous to you as well as to the elite guard: its beams reflect off walls, meaning you'll have to be very careful where you shoot to avoid bouncing a shot toward yourself!
>
> Luckily, the beams can only travel a certain maximum distance before becoming too weak to cause damage. You also know that if a beam hits a corner, it will bounce back in exactly the same direction. And of course, if the beam hits either you or the guard, it will stop immediately (albeit painfully).
>
> Write a function solution(dimensions, your_position, guard_position, distance) that gives an array of 2 integers of the width and height of the room, an array of 2 integers of your x and y coordinates in the room, an array of 2 integers of the guard's x and y coordinates in the room, and returns an integer of the number of distinct directions that you can fire to hit the elite guard, given the maximum distance that the beam can travel.
>
> The room has integer dimensions [1 < x_dim <= 1250, 1 < y_dim <= 1250]. You and the elite guard are both positioned on the integer lattice at different distinct positions (x, y) inside the room such that [0 < x < x_dim, 0 < y < y_dim]. Finally, the maximum distance that the beam can travel before becoming harmless will be given as an integer 1 < distance <= 10000.
>
> For example, if you and the elite guard were positioned in a room with dimensions [3, 2], your_position [1, 1], guard_position [2, 1], and a maximum shot distance of 4, you could shoot in seven different directions to hit the elite guard (given as vector bearings from your location): [1, 0], [1, 2], [1, -2], [3, 2], [3, -2], [-3, 2], and [-3, -2]. As specific examples, the shot at bearing [1, 0] is the straight line horizontal shot of distance 1, the shot at bearing [-3, -2] bounces off the left wall and then the bottom wall before hitting the elite guard with a total shot distance of sqrt(13), and the shot at bearing [1, 2] bounces off just the top wall before hitting the elite guard with a total shot distance of sqrt(5).

**What I've Tried**

```
import math
def solution(dimensions, your_position, guard_position, distance):
    positions = make_positions(dimensions, your_position, guard_position, distance) # Gets all the guard and "me" positions when reflecting the rooms. EG if the room is 3x2 and my position is 1,1 then some of the reflected positions will be 1,3 -1,1 etc
    ways = [] # Will store the ways to hit the target.
# This loop filters all the positions and keeps the one that make sense (eg if the bullet will hit me before it hits the target then it wont count it, or if shotting in the same direction can hit many targets it only counts one, it also takes care of the distance req)
    for p in positions:
        valid = True
        if p[0] <= distance and p[-1]: # If the distance is less than or equal to the max distance and it is towards the target (given by p[0]) then I consider this point
            for p2 in positions: # I go through all other shots I could take and make sure that this position is the shortest (eg if I can hit the 2 targets I only want to consider it as 1 hit as I will hit the one closest to me, and I want to make sure I don't hit myself before I hit the guard)
                if p2[1] == p[1] and p2[0] < p[0]:
                    valid = False

            if valid and p[2:4] not in ways:
                ways.append(p[2:4])
    return len(ways) # Returns the number of ways to hit the target

def make_positions(dimensions, your_position, guard_position, distance):
# This function returns all the mirrored positions (up, down, left, right)
    p2 = []
# Gets the maximum number of reflections needed based on the shot distance
    rooms_x = int(math.ceil(float(your_position[0] + distance)/dimensions[0]))
    rooms_y = int(math.ceil(float(your_position[1] + distance)/dimensions[1]))
    
    room_x_back = -1 * rooms_x
    room_y_back = -1 * rooms_y
# Check if I am on the edge so that I don't get weird reflections where I would be on the same spot
    if your_position[0] == 0:
        room_x_back = 0
    elif your_position[0] == dimensions[0]:
        rooms_x = 0
    if your_position[1] == 0:
        room_y_back = 0
    elif your_position[1] == dimensions[1]:
        rooms_y = 0
    for x in range(room_x_back, rooms_x):
        for y in range(room_y_back, rooms_y):
# Takes care of my position in this reflection
            x_pos, y_pos = get_position(dimensions, your_position, x, y) # Gets my new position (x,y)
            dist = get_distance(your_position[0], your_position[1], x_pos, y_pos) # Calculates my distance to my new position (this helps me identify if I will hit myself or the target later on if shooting in this direction can hit both)
            angle = get_angle(your_position[0], your_position[1], x_pos, y_pos) # This gives me the angle I would have to shoot in to hit the new (x,y)
            if dist > 0:
                p2.append([dist, angle, 0])
            
# Take care of the target position in this reflection (very much the same as the code above)
            x_pos, y_pos = get_position(dimensions, guard_position, x, y)
            dist = get_distance(your_position[0], your_position[1], x_pos, y_pos)
            angle = get_angle(your_position[0], your_position[1], x_pos, y_pos)
            p2.append([dist, angle, x_pos, y_pos, 1])
    return p2

def get_position(dimensions, position, x, y):
# Returns the reflected position
# If there are an odd number of reflections in one direction there is a pattern and similarly for evens so I handle both cases.
    if not x % 2:
        x_pos = (x) * dimensions[0] + position[0]
    else:
        x_pos = (x+1) * dimensions[0] - position[0]
    if not y % 2:
        y_pos = (y) * dimensions[1] + position[1]
    else:
        y_pos = (y+1) * dimensions[1] - position[1]
    return x_pos, y_pos

def get_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)

def get_angle(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    #if not x2-x1:
        #return float("inf") if y2 > y1 else float("-inf")
    return math.atan2(x2-x1,y2-y1)
```

My code currently uses the reflection property to find all guard positions and count them. I know it is not the cleanest but I'll fix that later.

I currently past 9/10 test cases with test case 3, not passing. Some of the examples I have gathered online and tested on my code (my code gives the correct answer for each of them):

solution([3,2],[1,1],[2,1],4) - I get 7

solution([2,5],[1,2],[1,4],11) - I get 27

solution([23,10],[6,4],[3,2],23) - I get 8

solution([300,275], [150,150], [185,100], 500) - I get 9

solution([1250,1250],[1000,1000],[500,400],10000) - I get 196

I have been looking at why I would fail a test case but can't find the reason. Any help?

Comment: I think, it would a good idea, to clean and comment the code first. Otherwise, we'd have to go through every line to understand what you are trying...

Comment: I added some comments that I think will help explain each piece of the code! Let me know if there are specific lines I should comment, I tried getting the important ones.

Comment: Couldn't follow the odd/even handling in get_position. Are you handling the corner scenarios?(I couldn't make out that, if you are, then ok)

Comment: @UgoDosReis The comments are at the right positions, but they are on a really high level, i.e., they dont help me that much. I don't think your code works. When I look at the directions for the example case, they are all wrong. I think you did not handle multireflections and your approach does not look like it might be able to do that easily.

Comment: I made a drawing with all the reflections eg 3+ reflections in each direction and noticed based on if it was an odd/even reflection that there was a pattern: for odds the position is ` (x) *  dimensions[0] + dimensions[0] - position[0]` and for even it is `(x) * dimensions[0] + position[0]`. I do this  for the x and y to get the position which I checked multiple times and it seems correct. I also pass `solution([2,5],[1,2],[1,4],11)` which has multiple reflections.

Comment: just to be clear. if you replace `return len(ways)` by `return ways`, does `solution([3, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], 4)`, return the correct result, i.e.: `[[1, 0], [1, 2], [1, -2], [3, 2], [3, -2], [-3, 2], [-3, -2]]` - or any other order of those directions?

Comment: Yup it returns the correct result for each of the test cases.

Comment: @UgoDosReis That is strange, when I run your code, I get `[[-2, -1], [-2, 3], [2, -1], [2, 1], [2, 3], [4, -1], [4, 3]]` for that case.

Comment: So the way I have it working is that it doesn't give directions like [3,2] but gives the position I'm shooting towards eg [3,2] starting from [1,1] will give [4,3]